# Ionic app show blank in mobile

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Recently I have developed an application in Ionic framework which work perfectly in my browser using `ionic serve --lab` command but when I install it in my mobile device using `ionic run` command in Android device it shows a blank white display. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to debug your app on mobile from your computer using chrome://inspect and open the console tab to see if there s any errors make sure to activate the developpement mode on your mobile plus the usb debug

Comment: What is the chrome inspector error saying ? chrome://inspect/#devices

Answer (score 0):

I feel you do not have USB debugging enabled on your phone.

Make sure you have USB debugging enabled on your device as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) in developer.android.com.

For more tips on ionic testing follow [testing guidelines from ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your program is not running without any errors on chrome, then first run it on a simulator using a command like `ionic cordova emulate android` and then go to your chrome browser and navigate to chrome://inspect/#devices page.

There, you'll see your emulator. If you click on "inspect" option under your device, you could find the device-specific error that stops your app from working.